# In ng-app application css media queries not working properly on ie9 and ie10

Tags: html, css, angularjs

In my AngularJS app, CSS media query is not working properly only on IE9 and IE10. Media query defined for small screen is effecting globally. It works only when I resize the browser or inspect the element.

No issues in other browsers like Chrome and Firefox. I've not tested this in IE10+ browser. It works in IE8+ when I remove AngularJS.
Here is my media query:

```html
@media (min-width: 0px) and (max-width: 767px) { 
    .col-sidebar{ width:100%}
    .col-content{ width:100%}
}
```

In large screen on IE10 browser, sidebar shows 100% width.

Here is my global css for large screen:

```
.col-sidebar{ width:30%}
.col-content{ width:70%}
```

Comment: You didn't define media query correctly. [Read this](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Comment: it works only when i resize the browser or inspect the element. also when i remove angular js

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle

Comment: @alirezasafian please find fiddler link http://jsfiddle.net/rizwanb/ybsp61ht/1/

Comment: I'm sorry to replay late.

Answer (score 0):

You used initial keyword [which is not supported in Internet Explore](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_initial.asp).

I removed all initial keyword and replaced with default value. [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ybsp61ht/4/)

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#header {
    height: 116px;
    background-color: #333;
}

#sidebar, #content {
    position: absolute;
    top: 7.2em;
    bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}

#sidebar {
    width: 392px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    z-index: 999;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: red;

}
#map_canvas {background-color: green;}
#content {
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 24em;
    right: 0;
    background-color: green;
}

#map_canvas {
    height: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    body {
        padding-bottom: 40px !important;
    }
    .box {
        width: 100%;
        }
    #sidebar {
        width: 100%;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        box-shadow: none;
        z-index: auto;
    }

    #sidebar, #content {
            bottom: auto;
            position: static;
    }

    #content {
        overflow: visible;
        left: auto;
        right: auto;
        height: 100%;
    }

}
```

Comment: thanks for your solution. i found issue, that is all ccs file not called in master page.

Comment: @RizwanBahauddeen do not use initial keyword.